# HighCharts Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: highcharts

First time messing around with HighCharts.js.

I'm pulling in a .csv and passing in the necessary arrays.  They're populated and valid but the charts still aren't displaying.

```
function buildChartsUSD(dayLabelsArray, usdSeriesArray) {
  $('#containerUSD').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'USD Daily Close',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'The Big Short',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: dayLabelsArray,
        labels:{rotation: 90, x:-20}
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'USD'
        },
        format: '{value:.2f}',
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        data: usdSeriesArray,
        name: 'USD'

    }]
});
};
```

The Y-axis would be values like 204000.83 - series data is getting a 'reference error data not defined' exception though the array usdSeriesArray is populated.  Any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: What does `usdSeriesArray` look like? What does `dayLabelsArray` look like?

Comment: dayLabelArray = ['Feb-24-2016', 'Feb-25-2016',...] and renders properly

Comment: usdSeriesArray = ['142332', '142332.28',...]

Comment: There is your issue. The data series you list is a set of strings. They should be numeric such that it is like `[142332, 142332.28,...] `.

Comment: @AdamGerard Is the questions answered? or do you still have any problems?

Comment: Question is answered thank you

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  Question answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by wergeld above, the issue had to do with the elements in the array.  They should have been numeric and not strings.  Hence,

[111, 222, 333,...] not ['111', '222', '333', ...]

Silly mistake and simple answer.